# JavaScript: drawing an array of images to the HTML5 canvas- array positions are reordered when removing them

Tags: javascript, arrays, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have the following JS function, which I'm using to detect when an image is dragged to a certain location on the HTML5 canvas:

```
function isHit(mouseX, mouseY, obj){
console.log("isHit has been called from within if statement in mousemove function");
console.log("draggingImage variable value = " +draggingImage);
if(draggingImage == true){
    console.log("if dragging image == true statment is being called");
    console.log("Value of selectedImage = " + selectedImage);
    console.log("Value of selectedImageArrayLocation = " + selectedImageArrayLocation);
    if(mouseY > 250){
        console.log("Value of obj.shape.index = " +obj.shape.index);
        if((mouseX > 80) && (mouseX < 200) && (selectedImageArrayLocation >= 0) && (selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets)){
            console.log("Correct");
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Correct! This is an asset because it is an item that can be bought or sold for cash.";
            selectedImage.remove();
            console.log("selectedImage has been removed: " + selectedImage);
        }else{
            console.log("Incorrect");
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Incorrect! This icon is an asset because it is an item that can be bought or sold for cash.";
        }
    }
}
}
```

If the image is dragged to the correct location, I want to remove it from the canvas, and provide the user with some feedback. If it is dragged to the wrong location, I want to leave the image on the canvas, and provide the user with feedback.

I am calling the above function from my `mousemove` function, whenever an image is being dragged (I have a boolean that is set to true whenever a `mousedown` is detected on an image, and set to false whenever a `mouseup` is detected.

At the moment, when an image is dragged to the correct location, it is removed from the canvas, and the user is provided with feedback, but the positions of the rest of the images in the array are then re-ordered.

I'm wondering if this is because the line `selectedImage.remove();` in my above function is removing the image from the array, and not just from the canvas?

How would I remove the image from the canvas, but not from the array, bearing in mind that I've drawn all of the images to the canvas using the KineticJS library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hiding the shape through:

```
selectedImage.hide();
```

Instead of removing it. The `hide()` method is built into KineticJS.
If even this does not work, perhaps set the opacity to 0:

```
selectedImage.setOpacity(0);
```

Comment: That's brilliant, cheers! Out of interest, by only hiding the image, and not removing it, is the image still 'on' the canvas, even though it's no longer visible? Or is it actually removed from the canvas? I noticed that when hovering the cursor over an image that is visible, the cursor changes from a pointer to a hand, but when an image is hidden, using the function you suggested, the cursor changes back to a pointer... presumably meaning that the image has been removed from the canvas?

Comment: I'm assuming that the `hide()` method is like using `visibility: hidden;` in CSS: The browser still pretends that it's there (the positions of the other elements don't change), but it doesn't trigger any events such as mouseover or onclick. The `setOpacity` function presumably does the same thing, except that it will still trigger event listeners on mouseover or on click. I'm not too sure, you'll have to test it out.